# virtual method of header give errors during g++ compilation

Tags: c++

I'm initiating to C++ and I'm struggling with a compiling problem

I have a source file "binomial.cpp" in which I define the methods of my classes :

```
#include "binomial.hpp"
using namespace std;


int Bernoulli::operator()(){
        return (rand() < p*RAND_MAX) ? a : b;
    };

int Binomial::operator()(){
        int result(0);
        for(int i(0);i<n;++i){
            int a;
            a = B();
            result += a;
            };
        return result;
    };
```

and a header file "binomial.hpp" where I declare all my classes :

```
#include <iostream>


#ifndef BINOMIAL
#define BINOMIAL
class RandVar {
    
    virtual int operator()() =0;
    
    
};
struct Bernoulli : public RandVar {
    Bernoulli(int a = -1,int b = 1, double p = 0.5) : a(a), b(b), p(p) {};
    int operator()(){};
    private:
    int a,b;
    double p;
    
};


class Binomial : public RandVar {
    public:
    Binomial(Bernoulli B, int n=2)
    : B(B), n(n) {}
    int operator()(){};
    private:
    Bernoulli B;
    int n;
};
#endif
```

But when I try to compile that through g++ using the command : `g++ -Wall binomial.cpp -o binomial` those errors occur :

```
binomial.hpp: In member function ‘virtual int Bernoulli::operator()()’:
binomial.hpp:14:19: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
  int operator()(){};
                   ^
binomial.hpp: In member function ‘virtual int Binomial::operator()()’:
binomial.hpp:26:19: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
  int operator()(){};
                   ^
binomial.cpp: At global scope:
binomial.cpp:4:5: error: redefinition of ‘int Bernoulli::operator()()’
 int Bernoulli::operator()(){
     ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from binomial.cpp:2:0:
binomial.hpp:14:6: note: ‘virtual int Bernoulli::operator()()’ previously defined here
  int operator()(){};
      ^~~~~~~~
binomial.cpp:8:5: error: redefinition of ‘int Binomial::operator()()’
 int Binomial::operator()(){
     ^~~~~~~~
In file included from binomial.cpp:2:0:
binomial.hpp:26:6: note: ‘virtual int Binomial::operator()()’ previously defined here
  int operator()(){};
      ^~~~~~~~
```

I don't really know how to fix that so if someone can take some time to help a beginner it would be great !

Comment: Did you read the error messages?

Comment: Fair point, but I remember when I started C++ how confusing "declarations" and "definitions" were. The precise lingo make it hard to figure what the compiler means, if you're not familiar with the terms.

Comment: at first look, you can see that the `operator()` function returns int in the declaration. But inside the function, you do not have a return statement.

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, press the green tick next to it to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace both

```
int operator()(){};
```

with

```
int operator()();
```

in the header files. You meant to provide declarations, not definitions. To provide just a declaration (not provide the code right away), just drop the `{}`.

Comment: There is also the missing return for `int Binomial::operator()()`.